# MySQL query Works first time through loop only

Tags: mysql

I am trying to inert about ~1000 records in into  MySQL. But my attempt below only 'inserts' on the first query. After that I gets the 'or die' error message. I tried changing the if statement to random numbers (other then five), but it always dies after the first insert. What am I doing wrong?

```
$i=0;
foreach(.....){
    if($>5){
        insert($name, $phone);
    }
}

function insert($n, $p){

    $dbhost = "---"; 
    $dbuser = "---";
    $dbpass = "---";
    $dbname = "---";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $query ="INSERT INTO foo (name, phone) VALUES ('$n', '$p')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');  
    mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: Two things are needed in order to answer : the table structure and the SQL error.

Comment: Connecting and disconnecting 1000 times is too much overhead and does more bad than good. What if the MySQL server is somewhere across a network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting a primary key error?

Comment: I am just seeing the, "Error connecting to mysql" message. How would i get a more detailed message?

Comment: Evidently, that was the problem. I set the primary key wrong; I needed to set it to autoindex when I set up the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is your code

```
$i=0;
foreach(.....){
    if($>5){
        insert($name, $phone);
    }
}

function insert($n, $p){

    $dbhost = "---"; 
    $dbuser = "---";
    $dbpass = "---";
    $dbname = "---";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $query ="INSERT INTO foo (name, phone) VALUES ('$n', '$p')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');  
    mysql_close();
}
```

Connecting to MySQL just to insert one row followed by [**disconnecting and reconnecting is a VERY EXPENSIVE OPERATION**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16973/877) !!!

Try reorganizing it like this :

```
$dbhost = "---"; 
$dbuser = "---";
$dbpass = "---";
$dbname = "---";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$i=0;
foreach(.....){
    if($>5){
        insert($name, $phone);
    }
}
mysql_close();

function insert($n, $p){
    $query ="INSERT INTO foo (name, phone) VALUES ('$n', '$p')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');  
}
```